# how to get latitude and longitude of a place using objective-c?

Tags: iphone

how to get latitude and longitude values of a particular place using objective-c ? Do I need to get this using Google Geocoding API or Is there any other way to get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iPhone only knows its current location (if using location-service). For getting the current location and for locations like: 10km east, 2km north from current location you can use the location-service (CoreLocation) but for any other location (which are identified via a name, street, text) you have to use a web-service like [Google Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/), [Open Street Map Nominatum](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim), [YahooMaps-Geocoding](http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/rest/V1/geocode.html) (yes, they have one...),  ...

Comment: Thank you for your reply Thomas. Can I use Google Geocoding API without including maps in my application ?

Comment: yes, you can. Take a look into the geocoding-api-docu I've posted. You just send an HTTP-GET to the google-server which then returns a xml- or json-result which you have to parse (eg. with TBXML). Here a sample-get:
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Munich,%20Germany&sensor=false
Dont forget to encode the search-string with the Percentage-Encoding like I've done in my sample-url (%20 is a space)